# How can I check if a file is newer that the target file in a shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script

How can I check if a file is newer that the target file?

In a shell script, intended to run on a Mac, I want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $SourceFile dateisgreater $TargetFile ] then
    echo "SourceFile is newer that Targetfile"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#/bin/bash
if [ "$SourceFile" -nt "$TargetFile" ]; then
    echo "SourceFile is newer than Targetfile"
fi
```

`-nt` means "newer than".

I've added quotes around the file names because if you need quotes on the echo, tehn you also need quotes on the file names...

Comment: Quoting around the variables is in case the values (the names of the files in this case) have white space. Without quoting and with white space, bash would not be able to parse the if test correctly.